# How do you force a local file sync within NetBeans?

Tags: svn, netbeans

I currently have a NetBeans php project setup to sync from my user directory to a different local directory /var/www/myproject .  This works great when I'm developing locally (adding, deleting and changing files).  The problem occurs when I do an update from source control and pull down changes from another developer.  NetBeans does not sync the project files after the source control update.  (I have tried the svn update from within the IDE and from a terminal prompt...same result).

Is there a way within the IDE to force the local sync?

Ubuntu 10.04
NetBeans 6.9.1
Source Control - SVN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've found, is to delete the whole project-directory within /var/www/vhosts/ or wherever your server files are (the local copy of real project folder, /var/www/myproject in your question). Then restart Netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I know is to **deactivate** the "*copy files from Sources Folder to another location*" option and then **reactivate** it.

Always save configuration changes.

Restarting the "copy files.." option always starts the local syncronization.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the folder name of the destination, and then copy the config filies, etc. if needed.
This way the config files are not lost, if you need to have them stored in the destination folder, and not in netbeans. (Autogenerated conf file for Drupal for instance, I tend to not have them in netbeans)
You can then delete the old destination folder, and create that one when you need to sync again.
It is my experience that it is only needed when files are changed outside of netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

You can also (in netbeans 7.4 + at least) set the checkbox 'Copy files on project open', on the Project properties screen (just underneath 'Copy files from sources folder....'), then close and reopen the project after you pull someone elses changes from SVN.